# Time -- Gone Eight?

Tags: time

I'm reading a novel set in the UK (I'm in Maryland, USA).  In the novel, someone asks the time; the reply is, "gone eight."  What does this mean, please?  Thank you.

Comment: *gone eight = **past** eight [o'clock]*

Comment: [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gone#gone__14)

Comment: @Andrew Leach Have you found anything to touch the answer below in a dictionary?

Answer (score 5):

[*gone*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/gone#2-1) with a time means *later than*, so *gone eight* means *after eight o'clock*.

You'd more often use it in circumstances to emphasise the lateness -

> It's already gone 9.30, I was supposed to be in work half an hour ago.

and although you can use it for things which have not yet happened

> I don't think he'll arrive 'till gone midnight

... you wouldn't use it to make plans:

> Let's meet up gone lunchtime

you'd use *after* in this case.

Comment: I was about to say this is genref. Then I read your answer. Much better than the bare bones in Collins. At least I agree with their classification as an adverb here (makes a change). But it's almost certainly the remains of a verbal construction.